# Haskell: overloading == for graph ADT

Tags: haskell, overloading

I have a declaration of graph for which I need to overload "==" operator in Haskell (problem from the book).

```
data Node a = Node {
label :: a,
adjacent :: [(a,Int)]
} deriving Show

data Network a = Graph [Node a] deriving Show
```

Basically, two graphs are equal if they have same vertices and edges (but Node's may be in different order in Network data type as well as list of adjacent vertices in Node data type). Have some difficulties in that, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

NOTE: My problem is with the equality check, not with the syntax of making instances of type classes.

Comment: the title was is different from what you actually want

Comment: if the title is confusing, then let me change it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import Data.Function (on)
import qualified Data.Map as M

instance Ord a => Eq (Network a) where
    (==) = (==) `on` f where
        f :: Ord a => Network a -> M.Map a (M.Map a Int)
        f (Graph nodes) = M.fromList $ map g nodes
        g :: Ord a => Node a -> (a, M.Map a Int)
        g node = (label node, M.fromList $ adjacent node)
```

What this implementation does:

- converts each network to a map
- tests those maps for equality

Because the maps are unordered (and the original lists contain no duplicates) the order of the original lists does not affect the output.

You might even be better off changing your `Node` and `Network` representations to use `Map`s.

Comment: do you have a link to the algorithm? i mean pseudocode or something in that manner?

Comment: Sorry, I just wrote it off the top of my head, and I wrote it in Haskell only.

Comment: i guess the most brilliant ideas always come from top of the head

Comment: by the way, how can i implement on function (hugs can't import Data.Function)

Comment: [Here is the source code to `on`.](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-Function.html#on)

Answer (score 6):

If you can't just use `deriving (Eq, Show)` then you have to implement it by hand.

```
instance (Eq a) => Eq (Node a) where
    n1 == n2 = (* Implement the equality check here *)

instance (Eq a) => Eq (Network a) where
    g1 == g2 = (* Implement the equality check here *)
```

This is really what that derive statement does for you automatically.

If you want more on typeclasses, I like Learn you a Haskell's explanation.

If you want help on actual equality checks, use `Data.Map` with the `fromList` function.

As for the nodes, this snippet should do it

```
(==) = (==) `on` label
```

or to be more explicit

```
n1 == n2 = label n1 == label n2
```

Comment: i know that i must make instance, the problem comes with exactly equality check

Comment: some recursive algorithm that i don't probably know

Comment: Can nodes have different adjacent nodes? Eg can 2 nodes have the same label?

Comment: graph is acyclic directed weighted, two nodes can't have the same label, and they probably may have different adjacent nodes

Comment: can you expalin a bit about Data.Map and fromList? how can mapping help me in checking for equality?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement Eq instance for Network:

```
instance Eq (Network a) where
    n1 == n2 = ...
```

More here:

http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-101

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Classes_and_types